# First Common Ancestor of a Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

If I have a binary search tree like this then what will be lowest common ancestor of nodes 6 and 1?

[image: Binary Search tree]

Comment: it is a test case to test whether the algorithm is running properly

Comment: `8` would be the answer in this case - but I have seen people answering `6` as well

Comment: is people answering 6 in the similar case or is there any difference in that case. Can you tell me the exact answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia definition of the [Lowest common ancestor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) I correct myself:

> The lowest common ancestor (LCA) is a concept in graph theory and
>   computer science. Let T be a rooted tree with n nodes. The lowest
>   common ancestor is defined between two nodes v and w as the lowest
>   node in T that has both v and w as descendants (**where we allow a node
>   to be a descendant of itself**).

So yes going by this definition the correct answer would be `6`. If this is an interview question would be good to clarify in advance with the interviewer.